# Display user info in confirmation page after a form

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, dynamic, get

I'm managing a donations site built with Wordpress and the Give WP plugin. I want to make a customized confirmation page where the donors can see their name, amount, and info related to the donation. My level of PHP is limited and the best thing I achieved is to display the name of the last donor, but not the current donor.

Also I have no clue on how to display the featured image or any field of the form.

This is the code I used:

```
$testquery = new Give_Payments_Query( array( 'number' => 1 ) );
$payments       = $testquery->get_payments();
if ( $payments ) {
    foreach ( $payments as $payment ) {
        $first_name = $payment->get_meta( '_give_donor_billing_first_name', true );
        $last_name = $payment->get_meta( '_give_donor_billing_last_name', true );
        $total  = give_donation_amount( $payment->ID, array( 'currency' => true ) );
?>
    <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 50px; font-family: neue-haas-grotesk-display,sans-serif; color: #a03828; margin-bottom: 30px;">¡Gracias <?php echo esc_html( $first_name); ?>!</span></p>
    <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 34px; font-family: neue-haas-grotesk-display,sans-serif; color: #1a1842; margin-bottom: 30px;">Su donativo se ha realizado con éxito.</span></p>
    <p style="text-align: center; font-family: acumin-pro,sans-serif; color: #1a1842;">Si lo desea puede consultar los detalles de su recibo o descargarlo.</p>
<?php
    }
}
```

I would apreciate if you could help me. Thanks!